# Find intersection of two ranges on line

Tags: geometry

I have two ranges on 2D line defined by edge points. How to get intersection of these ranges with minimum operations?

[image]

p1-p2 - first range

p3-p4 - second range

I want to get p3-p2 in this case (but in common case it can be any combination of points or empty range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the vectors $d_i=p_i-p_1$ for $i=2,3,4$ and calculate the dot products $s_i=d_2\cdot d_i$. Then intersect the ranges $[0,d_2]$ and $[d_3,d_4]$ as you'd intersect one-dimensional ranges, and in the result replace the dot products by the corresponding points.